# PHP Curl Script respond Error Msg but POSTMAN works?

Tags: php, json, curl

Following php code is working on post man app but not curl php script.
curl code correct but given response like only 'ERROR'. this same paramater is working on postman app.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://example.com/relay/relay/relay/device/XXXX/session/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/port_3480/data_request?id=scene&action=create';

$AuthToken = 'xxxxxx';
$AuthSigToken = 'YYYYY';

$aPostData = array('json' => '{"scene_name":"om","name":"om","groups":[{"delay":0,"actions":[{"device":"14","service":"urn:upnp-org:serviceId:HVAC_UserOperatingMode1","action":"SetModeTarget","arguments":[{"name":"NewModeTarget","value":"CoolOn"}]}]}],"triggers":[{"name":"tttttttt","enabled":1,"device":"12","template":"1","arguments":[{"id":1,"value":"0"}]}],"timers":[],"lua":"","users": "","modeStatus": "0","id": 1000001}');


$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

  $ch = curl_init ($url);     
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("MMSAuth:$AuthToken","MMSAuthSig:$AuthSigToken"));

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); //timeout in seconds

 if($aPostData != null)
  {
   $fields_string = '';
   foreach($aPostData as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
   $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($aPostData));
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
  }

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close ($ch);   
echo '<pre>';
print_r($error);

echo '@result=>';
print_R($result);

?>
```

When i have print result then display error like

```
 @result=>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    content-Type: 
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Tue, 20 Oct 2015 11:09:34 GMT
    Server: lighttpd/1.4.29

ERROR
```